# How to add content to html file in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiwebview

I want to add content to html file which is available in project resources.
for ex:- Below is  html which has some tag inside it

```
<body >
<div id="abc">
    <div>{feed}<br /></div>
    <div >{date}</div>
</div>
</body>
```

I want to replace {feed} ,{date} with some string in it and display that html in `UIwebview`
Please give me some pointers to achieve it 
Thanks in advance

Comment: u can use @ instead of feed and date then pass feed and data to [NSString stringWithForm@"html%@%@",feed,date]

Comment: Thanks all for ur answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Get your HTML file path.
NSString * htmlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YOUR_FILE_NAME" ofType:@"html"];

//get the file content to a NSString.
NSString *htmlContentString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

// Then you need to replace a string (say 'stringA') with new string (say 'stringB')
    htmlContentString = [htmlContentString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:stringA withString:stringB];

//Then load the new HTML string to your webView

[yourWebView loadHTMLString:htmlContentString baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Load the html string to NSMutableString
2. Search and replace the required string
3. use `UIWebView` method `- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL;` to load it.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str = @"<body >
<div id="abc">
    <div>{feed}<br /></div>
    <div >{date}</div>
</div>
</body>";

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{feed}"
                                     withString:@"YourString"];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{date}"
                                     withString:@"YourString"];
```

If you need add someting else to the html use `NSMutableString` instead of `NSString`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
NSString *feedString = @"Your feed string";
NSString *dateString = @"Your date string";
NSString* descHtmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<body ><div id="abc"><div>%@<br /></div><div >%@</div></div></body>", feedString, dateString];
```